# Solution of a congruence equation in a PID

Tags: congruences, principal-ideal-domains

> If $D$ is a PID and $a,b,m\in D$, then the equation:
>   $$
> ax\equiv b \pmod{m} 
> $$   has solution $x \in D$ iff $b$ divides $(a,m)$.

I have proved the left to right implication but I'm trying so hard the other and I don't get it. I will appreciate any suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: You mean $\ (a,m)\mid b,\,$ i.e. $\,(a,m)\supseteq (b),\,$ i.e. $\,(a,m)\ni b.\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ In a PID, $\,\ (a,b) = (\gcd(a,b))\,$ and $ $ divides = contains: $\,a\mid b\iff (a)\supseteq (b).\,$ Hence

$\gcd(a,m)\mid b\iff (a,m)=(\gcd(a,m))\supseteq(b)\iff b = ax+my\iff b\equiv ax\pmod{m}$

Comment: Ooooooooooooh I see it! Thank you so much! :)